# How do I burn ubuntu iso image to DVD on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-12.04, dvd-burning

I downloaded ubuntu 12.04 LTS from [this site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), and I am trying to follow the instructions about how to burn the `iso` image to DVD according to [this page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows) but I don't see the image on desktop as shown on the first picture on that page. What am I doing wrong? I am on Windows 7.

Comment: You probably downloaded it to a different folder. You should try searching for `ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop` in Start Menu search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, your download is in your `Downloads`-folder.

- Path: `C:\Users\yourUsername\Downloads`

If the `iso`-file isn't there, search in the search-bar the file.

1. Click on the <kbd>Windows</kbd>-Button on the lower-left.
2. Now write in the search-field for `ubuntu`.
3. Now you should see the file.
4. Rightclick on it and open the path.

Then, you can follow these easy steps:

> 1. Insert a recordable CD, DVD, or Blu‑ray Disc into your disc burner.
> 2. Open Computer by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, and then clicking Computer.
> 3. In Windows Explorer, find the disc image file, and then double-click it.
> 4. If you have more than one disc burner, from the Disc burner list in Windows Disc Image Burner, click the burner that you want to use.
> 5. (Optional) If you want to verify that the disc image was burned correctly to the disc, select the Verify disc after burning check box.
> 6. If the integrity of disc image file is critical (for example, the disc image file contains a firmware update), you should select this
>      check box.
> 7. Click Burn to burn the disc.

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/burn-a-cd-or-dvd-from-an-iso-file)

Answer (score 1):

The disk image is probably in your Downloads folder. Many web browsers (like Firefox) will download to there by default.