# Unable to boot Ubuntu installer from a CD/DVD - "Please select a proper boot device"

Tags: ubuntu, boot, dvd

I am a Windows user and I decided to install Ubuntu in dual mode.

So, I downloaded an Ubuntu ISO image from [ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com). Next, I used Windows File Explorer to burn the ISO to my DVD/CD. Then I restarted my computer and from the boot options I selected the CD/DVD drive. It showed `Please select a proper boot device`. Then it restarted and booted into Windows normally.

I guess I have to install GRUB bootloader onto my CD/DVD and then boot it, but I don't have any idea of how to do that.

Comment: You may want to try using something other than Windows to burn the DVD. Try [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com).

Comment: Have you followed [How to burn a DVD on Windows](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-windows)? Also, check [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/662097/880618).

Comment: ubuntu tutorial recommends using infra-recoder i guess i'll have to give that one a try..btw how do i verify if my .iso is curropted?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! The question is fair, though I hope you don't mind me editing it slightly to change the phrasing of the title and one of the tags. We also appreciate your politeness, but  I have removed the 'thanks in advance' as there is a preference to focus on the technical aspects of questions on here (there's a bit of a debate about it at the moment, but don't worry for now). If you like, you can [edit your question further](https://superuser.com/posts/1319409/edit). :)

Comment: @bertieb Is there a meta post I could see about removing 'thanks' on questions? I would really appreciate that because I remove it as well but gets me thinking. Thanks

Comment: @TiagoCaldeira You may have seen the [recent blog post about Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/?cb=1), which may cause a rethink of [the policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021) (note date of *2009*). I'm not sure I would edit a question just to remove 'thanks', but I might take it out if I'm editing anyway- edits should always strive to *significantly* improve a post. However, if there was a very wordy one "THX 4 UR HELP GUISE!! UR ALL DA BEST <3 <3 <3" I would take that out... a judgement call sometimes.

Comment: In addition, policy is somewhat in the eye of the beholder/site. For example, from my anecdotal browsing, mods on RPG.se are *very* quick to remove [answers in comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6534), because they bypass the usual moderation pathways. In theory, answers should only be answers (and not comments) everywhere, but you can see plenty of them on other SE sites.

Comment: In theory, all bad posts should be downvotes and/or flagged and/or VTC'd. In (my own) practice, I am a bit more tolerant of new users; and a bit more liberal in my use of upvotes rather than downvotes. Others differ!

Comment: Lastly, there is a general principle (sort of "Rule 0"), only to be invoked in *exceptional* circumstances: if something is helpful or beneficial, there is an argument to keep it, regardless of rules or policy which says otherwise. I can't find a citation for this, however.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess I have to install GRUB bootloader onto my CD/DVD and then boot it, but I don't have any idea of how I do it.

First up, you don't need to install grub onto your media! The ISOs are set up to be self-booting and don't need a separate bootloader.

Grub *can* be used to boot Ubuntu once it is installed, but the very good installer will guide you through that process.

More info, if you're interested: [*What exactly is GRUB?*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/347203/what-exactly-is-grub) over at AskUbuntu.

## Using Writable Media to Install Ubuntu

### Verify the Image

Fortunately, Ubuntu has [an entire wiki page dedicated to burning ISOs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto).

Firstly, if may be worth verifying your download. There is [a way to do this using `md5sum`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM), although that isn't built into Windows:

> Windows does not come with md5sum. You must download one from another location, preferably one that you trust. There are command line utilities (md5sum.exe) that work similarly to the Unix utility; one public domain version with source is available from Fourmilab, but the version available from Cygwin is probably easier to install and update, and Cygwin is also recommended and trusted as the source for many more Unixy utilities. Once installed, Cygwin's md5sum behaves exactly as described in MD5SUM on Linux above.

You could also use something like [winMD5sum](http://www.nullriver.com/downloads/Install-winMd5Sum.exe) to do the same thing using a GUI.

### Burning the ISO

Depending on how you did it, you may have fallen afoul of the process at this stage.

> Unlike a regular data file, the ISO file cannot be simply dragged and dropped or copied directly onto a disc. It needs to be burned in a specific way that expands/extracts the image so you have usable files on your disc.

But don't be dissuaded- it can be done! The wiki suggests two methods:

1. Using Explorer:

   > - Right-click on an ISO image and choose “Burn disc image”
   > - Select a disk burner (drive) and press "Burn"
   > - If you check “Verify disc after burning”, it will verify that the ISO image has been burned correctly.
2. Using a third-party tool

   > - Download and install [Infra Recorder](http://infrarecorder.org/), a free and open source image burning program
   > - Insert a blank CD in the drive and select Do nothing or Cancel if an autorun dialog pops up
   > - Open Infra Recorder and click the 'Write Image' button in the main screen.
   > - Select the Ubuntu CD image file you want to use, then click 'Open'.
   > - Click 'OK'

See below:

[image: infrarecorder]

With an image that has been verified (both after download and after writing) you should be good to boot without needing to install grub to do that!

---

<sup>Image and above heavily based on [Ubuntu Wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto).</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your copy of Ubuntu image is corrupted. You can try downloading fresh copy of Ubuntu and try installing it from a live USB.
Good Luck.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is more of a comment than an answer. Please consider reworking this to include relevant details such as how to avoid or check for ISO corruption. Likewise, if you are recommending installing from a live USB, some clues or procedures as to how that could be done would be extremely helpful and relevant.